# Is it possible to use a vector for opengl vertex array?

Tags: c++, opengl

I want my class `Vector3f` to store index pointes for my cuboid (made from triangles).

Heres what I would push to the vector.

```
    vector<Vector3f> I;

    I.push_back(Vector3f(1,   0,   2));     //front
    I.push_back(Vector3f(2,   0,   3));
    I.push_back(Vector3f(4,   5,   7));         //back
    I.push_back(Vector3f(7,   5,   6));
    I.push_back(Vector3f(0,   4,   3));     //left
    I.push_back(Vector3f(3,   4,   7));     
    I.push_back(Vector3f(5,   1,   6));     //right
    I.push_back(Vector3f(6,   1,   2));
    I.push_back(Vector3f(7,   6,   3));     //up
    I.push_back(Vector3f(3,   6,   2));
    I.push_back(Vector3f(1,   0,   5));     //down
    I.push_back(Vector3f(5,   0,   4));
```

Can vertex arrays read from classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Vector3f is POD

`&I[0]` will give your a `float *` which you can pass to `glBufferData`